# Memory leak while using in_memory ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, memory, in-memory

I am running a Python script to make point feature layer from a series of netCDF files and then perform a spatial join with a number of polygons and save the results as a table. I am using `arcpy.MakeNetCDFFeatureLayer_md` and address its output to a variable in 'in_memory' workspace. My problem is that even though I am deleting the 'in_memory' after each loop using `arcpy.Delete_management('in_memory')`, it does not free up my RAM and after a couple of iterations I run into Memory Error. The function that is being called for each netCDF file looks like this:

```
def spatialJoin(nc):
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'
    arcpy.MakeNetCDFFeatureLayer_md(nc, "SM", "lon", "lat", "SMPoints", "time;lat;lon", "", "", "", "BY_VALUE")

    <does the spatial join>

    print arcpy.Exists('SMPoints')
    arcpy.Delete_management('SMPoints')
    print arcpy.Exists('SMPoints')
```

And the console prints:

```
True
False
```

for each iteration, which means Delete_management is working. But checking the python process in windows task manager shows that the data is piling up in RAM! I have tried deleting individual features inside 'in_memory' as well as deleting the whole 'in_memory' but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something here?

P.S. Spatial join does not affect the problem here, problem exists even when I completely comment out the spatial join section.

Comment: It's nasty, but you could try and delete the arcpy module import after each iteration then re import it.

Comment: Did you see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19684/clearing-cache-memory-using-python? Also it's worthwhile to have a look at http://geeohspatial.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/dealing-with-arcpy-memory-leaks.html

Comment: Thanks @fatih_dur, the second link was useful. I managed to free up the memory by using multiprocessing module. It slowed down the process a bit, but the memory leak has stopped ;)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to set your environment workspace to in_memory as you are doing in your script, so you can drop this line:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = 'in_memory'
```

Also, ensure that you are using double-quotes when referencing your in_memory workspace inside of the geoprocessing tool.

```
arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
```

Comment: "ensure that you are using double-quotes when referencing your in_memory workspace" - that's a new one for me, can you explain/reference the double-quotes requirement over single-quotes?

Comment: Thanks @Radar, but changing to double-quote didn't help!